# how to understand tar minus

Tags: tar, curl

Lately I ran into a command:

```
curl https://start.spring.io/starter.tgz -d dependencies=webflux,actuator | tar -xzvf -
```

`curl` itself does not download the `tgz` file, since it is not `wget`. `tar -xzvf` does not download any file either. But `tar -xzvf -` does "download" files. I didn't find any `-` explanation in `tar` manpage, and I don't think it relates to login shell. I guess it is the shell I used. What is this `-`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curl` **does** download the file. As opposed to `wget`, it writes the downloaded file to `stdout` unless you specify `-o` option to save the file.
As to the `-` in tar command, it goes together with the `-f` option, and you can find the explanation in `info tar`, section `6.1 Choosing and Naming Archive Files` :

> If you use '-' as an ARCHIVE-NAME, 'tar' reads the archive from
>   standard input (when listing or extracting files), or writes it to
>   standard output (when creating an archive).  If you use '-' as an
>   ARCHIVE-NAME when modifying an archive, 'tar' reads the original archive
>   from its standard input and writes the entire new archive to its
>   standard output.

Comment: The new thing to me is many commands like `cat | grep` would read stdin without being explicitly told so (like using parameter `-`), and at the same time these commands could be given a file to work on. While tar is special...

Comment: Actually `tar` is _not_ special.  You should read the `cat` manual.  You are in for a surprise.  A further surprise awaits at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41842/5132 .

Answer (score 1):

Curl download the file and send it to STDOUT. Same can be done with `wget`.

Then pipe (`|`) send this file to STDIN of `tar` command. And this dash (`-`) tell tar to use STDIN for file instead of file from filesystem.