# Upload a file with lsh

Tags: ssh

How do I upload a local file to a remote machine running  over SSH with `lsh`? There are enough examples on the Internet for `ssh` but I am interested in doing it with `lsh`.

Here is what I tried with an MP3 file:

```
$ cat file.mp3 | lsh -l pi -c aes256-ctr --sloppy-host-authentication raspberrypi.local "cat > file.mp3"
$ lsh -l pi -c aes256-ctr --sloppy-host-authentication raspberrypi.local "cat > file.mp3" < file.mp3
$ tar -c file.mp3 | lsh -l pi -c aes256-ctr --sloppy-host-authentication raspberrypi.local "tar -x"
```

All of this results in a file named exactly as the file which I am sending but completely empty.

```
$ ls -l file.mp3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 0 Feb 24 06:55 file.mp3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From another look at the [documentation](https://www.lysator.liu.se/%7Enisse/lsh/lsh.html#lsh%20basics) I noticed that I've overlooked `-f -`. `-f` instructs `tar` to use an archive file. `-` [represents standard input or standard output respectively](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41828/423679). So, this worked:

```
$ tar -cf - file.mp3 | lsh -l pi -c aes256-ctr --sloppy-host-authentication raspberrypi.local "tar -xf -"
```

---

To upload a single file, another example is given [in section 3.5 of the Texinfo manual of GNU lsh](https://www.lysator.liu.se/%7Enisse/lsh/lsh.html#public-key). It uses input and output reditrection and does not require `tar`. In the above example, it would be:

```
$ lsh -l pi -c aes256-ctr --sloppy-host-authentication raspberrypi.local '>file.mp3' <file.mp3
```

However, that creates just an empty file on my systems as well as

```
$ >testfile2 <testfile1
```

I needed to add `cat`:

```
$ lsh -l pi -c aes256-ctr --sloppy-host-authentication raspberrypi.local 'cat >file.mp3' <file.mp3
```