# What is the practical purpose of "./" in front of relative file paths (in the output from "find")?

Tags: command-line, find, filenames, unix-philosophy

Why are some relative file paths displayed in the form of `./file`, instead of just `file`? For example, when I do:

```
find .
```

I get this output:

```
./file1
./file2
./file3
```

What is the practical purpose, other than making the path more confusing? It's not like it is preventing me from some accident. Both are relative paths, and `cat ./file1` works same as `cat file1`.

Is this behavior coming from `find` command, or is it some system-wide c library?

OK, I understand why using `./file` for `-exec` construct is necessary (to make sure I have `... | xargs rm ./-i`, and not `... | xargs rm -i`).

But in what situation would missing `./` break anything when using `-print` statement?

I am trying to construct any statement that breaks something:

```
touch -- -b -d -f -i
find -printf '%P\n' | sort

-b
-d
-f
-i
```

Everything works fine.

Just out of curiosity, how could I construct a `-print` statement that would demonstrate this issue?

Comment: that comes from `find`, libc has nothing to with that.

Comment: Your update mixes `-exec` and `xargs`. The latter shows the problem with `-print`. If you use `-exec`, you don’t need `xargs`; if you’re using `xargs`, you’d end up with `find -printf '%P\0' | xargs -0 rm` which would break. (It’s trivially fixable with `rm --` on systems where `rm` recognises `--`, but hopefully it still demonstrates the issue.)

Comment: you can install `.deb` with apt. Example `apt install discord` installs from sources, and `apt install ./discord` installs local file called "discord" in the current dir

Comment: "What is the practical purpose, other than making the path more confusing?" – Making the path less confusing. I mean *for me* `./something` is less confusing than `something`. The latter does not have to be a path, but the former almost certainly is.

Comment: This is Unix. The output of `-print` could be the *input* to anything. `find` doesn't make assumptions.

Comment: `find . .. -prune` prints `.` and `..`, `find . .. -maxdepth 1` prints `. ./file1... .. ../file2`... Would you like it to special-case `.` and remove the `./` prefixes, for cosmetic purposes at the expense of safety and portability?

Comment: @BrianLeishman that should be an answer

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This behaviour comes from `find`, and [is specified by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html):

> Each *path* operand shall be evaluated unaltered as it was provided, including all trailing <slash> characters; all pathnames for other files encountered in the hierarchy shall consist of the concatenation of the current *path* operand, a <slash> if the current path operand did not end in one, and the filename relative to the *path* operand.

The default action, `-print`, outputs the full pathname to standard out.

`find` outputs the paths of files it finds starting from the path(s) given on its command line.

```
find .
```

asks `find` to look for files under `.` and its subdirectories, and it presents the results starting with `./`;

```
find foo
```

would do the same but starting with `foo`, and it would produce results starting with `foo/`.

I don’t think `find` does this specifically to prevent *problems* with un-prefixed file names; rather, it does this for consistency — regardless of the path provided as argument, the output of `-print` always starts with that path.

With the GNU implementation of `find`, you can strip the initial path off the start of the printed file by using `-printf '%P\n'` in place of `-print`. For instance with `find foo/bar -name file -printf '%P\n'` or `find . -name file -printf '%P\n'`, you'd get `dir/file` instead of `foo/bar/dir/file` or `./dir/file` for those files.

More generally, having `./` as a prefix can help prevent errors, *e.g.* if you have files with names starting with dashes; for example if you have a file named `-f`, `rm -f` won’t delete it, but `rm ./-f` will.

When running commands with a shell or with `exec*p()` standard C functions (and their equivalent in other languages), when the command name doesn't contain a `/`, the path of command is looked in `$PATH` instead of being interpreted as a relative path (the file in the current working directory). Same applies for the argument to the `.` / `source` special builtins of several shells (including POSIX compliant `sh` implementations). Using `./cmd` in that case instead of `cmd`, which is another way to specify the same relative path, but with a `/` in it is how you typically invoke a command stored in the current working directory.

Comment: "rather, it does this for consistency" -- One could argue that printing `foo/` is not necessary either, but it *is* because `find` can accept multiple starting points, which I think is the key reason. For example, the need to include the prefix is more apparent with `find . foo bar`.

Comment: @JoL: I strongly dispute your hypothetical argument.  Every output from ```find … -print``` can, in principle, be used as an argument to another command (such as `cat`, `grep`, `ls` or `stat`) via a mechanism such as copy & paste or `xargs`.  (Let’s, for the moment, set aside the problems with names that begin with **`-`**, contain newline(s), and other oddities.)  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  If `find` finds `file1` in **`.`**, then it can certainly be argued that saying `file1` and saying `./file1` are equally useful.  But, if `find foo/bar` finds `file42` in subdirectory `baz`, then outputting `foo/bar/baz/file42` is ***much*** more useful than outputting just `file42` or `baz/file42`.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' I agree, and is more useful for piping in scripts to avoid prepending to the output of the print to some other command. If I want to do something with all found files, I don't need to prepend the path from the working directory onto it.

Comment: and, if one really despises the leading `./` then there's always `find * ...`

Comment: @keithpjolley, `find *` is wrong / suboptimal for several reasons: it skips hidden files (in the current directory only), it behaves badly if there's no non-hidden file in the current directory. It chokes on file names that start with `-` or are `find` predicates. It may fail if there are too many files in the current directory (note that compared to `find .`, it also sorts the list of files)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas -- agree it's suboptimal. i wouldn't use it. but it's not necessarily wrong depending on use case.

Answer (score 11):

There is no practical use when we talk about ordinary files. But when we talk about executable files it make sense. When you execute (and `file1` is located in current directory):

```
file1
```

shell search for executable file in all the paths in your PATH variable. And will execute this file only if you have in PATH something like: `:.:` (current directory is in PATH search). Instead of this very unwise setting you can run `file1`, located in current directory by:

```
./file1
```

Comment: i do not have `.` in my `PATH` (i prefer to know what i am executing) but i know many people who do. why is it `very unwise` in a nutshell?

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith, it open a backdoor to execute command located in current directory. This can be used for malicious activities (simplify them). Or can lead to actions by mistake (which actions can be sometime devastated)

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith, and this is one of the security controls in hardening lists of recommendations in some huge companies.

Comment: very well said regarding `backdoor to execute command located in current directory`. that in itself is a huge security issue i think. the secondary reason is the one i talked about `lead to actions by mistake`. also good to know about best practices recommendation.

Comment: Re "*There is no practical use when we talk about ordinary files.*",  It can, actually. Consider a file whose name starts with `-`.

Comment: @ikegami, for this there is `--`. And how many (normal) people will make files, with name starting with dash?

Comment: @Romeo Ninov, Yes, GNU has `--`. But GNU isn't everything. And while `--` can be used, it rarely is. They assume, like you, that they will *never* encounter a file starting with `-`. But that overlooks maliciousness and mistakes (such as copying text into a terminal that results in weird file names getting created). Prepending the path nicely avoids all of that.

Comment: @ikegami, Check here, its not only GNU: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/570729/where-is-the-double-dash-argument-documented

Comment: It's still up to every program that accepts command-line arguments to recognize `--` as a special argument, though. There is no *requirement* (even in POSIX, which I believe mandates it for its own utilities) that any given program support that convention.

Answer (score 5):

Many commands in Linux receive `-` as a special file denoting stdin, therefore to indicate a file whose name is really `-` you must use `./-`. See

- [Usage of dash (-) in place of a filename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16357/44425)
- [What does dash "-" at the end of a command mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41828/44425)

Besides `-` is also used for arguments, so if you want to work with file names starting with `-` like `--file` you have to use `./--file`. That's also why if you want to grep a pattern starting with `-` you must use `grep -e --pattern`. See [How to "less" a file named "-"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/210202/44425)

Comment: Everything but the last point is correct. The reason why you have to use `grep --pattern` if the pattern begins with a dash is because otherwise the pattern will be confused with an argument, it is not a filename which will be confused with anything.

Comment: a pattern beginning with `-` will be confused with an argument, exactly the same as a file name beginning with `-`. That's why some method to differentiate them with a normal argument. What's wrong with that?

Comment: (1) Talking about *other potential arguments* that begin with **`-`** is wandering off-topic, since you’re protecting them with **``-e``** and not **``./``**. (2) It’s confusing when you say you’re talking about things “starting with **`-`**” but then show only examples starting with **`--`** — especially when you say `--pattern` rather than *`--pattern`* or something like `'-foo.*bar'`.